# Typing text with testcafe is slow in our app for a particular page, dropdown actions in that page are executing fast

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I try to enter the text first name in the input text field is executing more than 50 times in the background, like the below status bar is blinking in Green color for more than 50 times.
Even entering the Credit card number, name entering is also having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and add required information and sample code to reproduce the issue. If you can't share the info publicly, please send it to support@devexpress.com